# Reference using $ symbol not working in my vs code

Tags: android, react-native, reference

I am writing a application in react native for which I am referencing the  formattedCatgories in description but it is taking as string. I am not able to notify the problem. Please help me to get out of this problem.[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r71B1.png)
[Output in the mobile Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2lyK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using ' instead of ` . Thats the reason why it doesn't work.
You need to use template literals, here is the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals